# CloudQueue.AddMessage don't valorize ID and PopReceipt property in the message

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

In the parameter of the entrypoint of a function I have declared a Queue as

```
[Queue("QRefresh")] CloudQueue qRefresh
```

in the body of the function i add a message:

```
await qRefresh.AddMessageAsync (SubId, null,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900),null,null);
```

**After that SubId and SubId.PopReceipt are both null instead they should be valorized   so I can't manage the message in the queue.**
The message is correctly inserted in the queue and is hidden. But it became visibile after 900 seconds.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code before `AddMessageAsync ` and what exactly you expect after?

Comment: Indeed, curious about how you're initializing the queue message (SubId) as having that being null is not making much sense.

Comment: CloudQueueMessage SubId = new CloudQueueMessage(responseSub scription.Id); where the parameter is a string

Comment: CloudQueueMessage SubId = new CloudQueueMessage(responseSub scription.Id); where the parameter is a string. So the object isn't null but the 2 properties are null. As from documentation after the call to Addmessage they should be valorized. The CloudTable object is from a bing from Azure Function

Answer (score 0):

Seems i found the issue. I'm using azure functions and seems that the assembly WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.1.0 that is binded in the Azure Function CLI doesn't support Addmessage popupReceipt correctly. On the other hand is not possible to add a newer versions of the assembly becouse it cause bind error.